# Sort data in range of Columns by value in one Column

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort data in range `Range("G1:J" & LastrowProjectList)` alphabetically by the value in column `H`. The following code does not work. I know the problem is the `.Range("H")`, but I don't know how to fix this. My data does not have headers. Data starts on `row 1`.

```
Sheets("VBA_Data").Range("G1:J" & LastrowProjectList).Sort Key1:=Sheets("VBA_Data").Range("H"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sheets("VBA_Data").Range("G1:J" & LastrowProjectList).Sort Key1:=Sheets("VBA_Data").Range("H1:H" & LastrowProjectList), Order1:=xlAscending
```

`.Range("H"), Order1:=xlAscending` should be `.Range("H1:H" & LastrowProjectList), Order1:=xlAscending`

Comment: Split second faster ;)

Comment: @KresimirL. - Probably 4 or 5 secs ;). You could have kept your answer.